# Android: gravity ImageView in RelativeLayout failed

Tags: android, android-relativelayout, layout-gravity

I would like to align this `ImageView` in `center` (horizontal and vertical):

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/titletab"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/slidingtab_icon_header"
    android:gravity="center">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/icon"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/slidingtab_item_icon_size"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/slidingtab_item_icon_size"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_event_black_18dp"/>

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="@color/sliding_tab_border_color"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

If I don't add the line (the `View`) after my `ImageView` it's perfect, it's work, but with this line the `gravity` doesn't work.

Thanks by advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change some property and your view is perfect. Just check below and you see I change gravity property in .

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/titletab"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/slidingtab_icon_header"
    >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/icon"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/slidingtab_item_icon_size"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/slidingtab_item_icon_size"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"/>

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="@color/sliding_tab_border_color"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

You need to use

```
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
android:layout_centerVertical="true"
```

instead of

```
android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
```

because This is works in **LinearLayout**.
But, for **RelativeLayout** you need to use above property for gravity set.

Answer (score 1):

Try `android:layout_centerInParent="true"` property of `Relativelayout` and remove the `gravity`.

```
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/icon"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/slidingtab_item_icon_size"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/slidingtab_item_icon_size"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_event_black_18dp"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You shoud use layout_alignBottom instead layout_alignParentBottom in View element.

```
<View
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/icon"
    android:background="@color/sliding_tab_border_color" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your code with this .
It is working and i changed the icon to the one which was available with me, you can use your icon

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/titletab"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/slidingtab_icon_header">



    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/icon"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/slidingtab_item_icon_size"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/slidingtab_item_icon_size"
        android:src="@drawable/abc_ic_ab_back_mtrl_am_alpha"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/li">

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use one more layout element to merge `ImageView` and `View` elements. Like this;

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/titletab"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/slidingtab_icon_header"
    android:gravity="center">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/icon"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/slidingtab_item_icon_size"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/slidingtab_item_icon_size"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_event_black_18dp"/>

        <View
            android:layout_below="@+id/icon"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:background="@color/sliding_tab_border_color"/>

    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```